# Mathematical way of getting set of numbers from one number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript, but I think that the idea applies across all languages. The idea is if you have 1 of 4 numbers you can get the other numbers. Something like this:

```
1 = 234
2 = 134
3 = 124
4 = 123
```

If you have 1 you output 234, and etc. whats the most efficient way to do this? Do you have to use arrays, loops?

**something like:**

```
var fruits = ["#apple", "#orange", "#peach"];
for (i = 0; i <= fruits.length-1; i++) {
    $(fruits[i]).show;
    $(fruits[WANT TO BE not i]).hide;//on loop would want to be other number besides i
    $(fruits[WANT TO BE not i]).hide;//on loop would want to be other number besides i
}
```

Comment: i think what your looking for is a `map`, implemented as an associative array

Comment: Why not just stick all the dom elements in a specific class, hide all of those elements and then only show the one that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think it's overkill, but if you *need* to do this with a use case that I can't imagine, you can always do this (using your fruits example):

```
var fruits = ["#apple", "#orange", "#peach"];

function showOne(n)
{
    for(i = 0; i < fruits.length; ++i)
    {
        if(n != i)
        {
            $(fruits[i]).hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $(fruits[i]).show();
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    showOne(2);
});
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/N9KXT/)**

**Edit:**

A few things based on viewing your source (1 and 2 are just my own opinion :)):

1. There's **no** question that I'd break all of those into individual pages. Not only do they not logically belong together, but I would *hate* to see the end result code (horrendous bloat).
2. On top of splitting the pages up, I would also have most of that functionality in the back end, not client side.
3. If you're set on doing this all client side, then I'd actually completely change the logic that you have:

HTML:

```
<a onclick="nav('slides'); return false;" href="#slides">Edit Slides</a>
<a onclick="nav('pages'); return false;" href="#pages">Edit Pages</a>
<a onclick="nav('projects'); return false;" href="#projects">Edit Projects</a>
```

Script:

```
function nav(panel)
{
    $('.section').hide();
    $(panel).show();
}
```

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). No reason to over-complicate things :)

Comment: thank you, but I am trying to avoid using a function / arguments.

Comment: why would you ever want to do that??... of course, other than *wanting* to have spaghetti code littering your projects..

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about efficiency, but since you are already using jquery, why not do:

```
<div id="apple" class="fruit">...</div>
<div id="orange" class="fruit">...</div>
<div id="peach" class="fruit">...</div>

$('.fruit').click(function() {
   $('.fruit').hide();
   $(this).show();
});
```

EDIT:

If I correctly identify your need, you want to show slide 2 everytime users click on 2 on Edit Slides.

In that case, you can attach id and class to the slides you want to show, like so:

```
<div id="slide_1" class="slide"><img src="1.jpg" /></div>
<div id="slide_2" class="slide"><img src="2.jpg" /></div>
<div id="slide_3" class="slide"><img src="3.jpg" /></div>
```

and add rel to your a

```
<ul class="navigationList">
   <li><a href="#" rel="slide_1">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" rel="slide_2">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" rel="slide_3">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now the javascript:

```
$('ul.navigationList li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var slideId = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.slide').hide();
    $('#' + slideId).show();
    return false;
});
```

Again this is only one of the ways of doing it.

Comment: I'm just giving you a general idea on how to achieve what you want, if you want a specific html / js answer, then post your html as well